# How to get a file resource in JSF project

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, url, classloader

I am trying to write a simple JSF application to let a user login on a web browser then my application should verify the users credentials on a MySQL database.

I am having trouble getting my code to see the database.properties file.  I use the following code for all my stand alone database programs but I had to make some modifications for this JSF application that I am writing.

About 3/4 of the way down the following line throws a ClassNotFoundException because my url variable is null and I don't know why:
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(url.getFile()); // Do this if on Server

Can anyone help me?  Thanks!  The code in question is in the first half of method init(String fileName).

Below is the entire class for getting the data source:

```
package com.gmail.gmjord.datasource;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * A simple data source for getting database connections.
 */
public class SimpleDataSource {
    private static String urlString;
    private static String username;
    private static String password;

    /**
     * Initializes the data source.
     * 
     * @param fileName
     *            the name of the property file that contains the database
     *            driver, URL, username, and password
     */
    public static void init(String fileName) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        // ****************** Added code for getting resource on a server
        // *********************
        System.out.println("In SimpleDataSource.init()");
        **Class cls = Class.forName("com.gmail.gmjord.datasource.SimpleDataSource");**

        System.out.println("Made it here 1");
        // returns the ClassLoader object associated with this Class
        ClassLoader cLoader = cls.getClassLoader();
        System.out.println("Made it here 2");

        System.out.println(cLoader.getClass());

        // finds resource with the given name
        URL url = cLoader.getResource(fileName); // This is the original line I copied from the web page
        //URL url = cls.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName); // This is TA's way
        System.out.println("Made it here 3");
        System.out.println("File: " + fileName);
        System.out.println("url Value = " + url);

        // ********* End of code for getting resource on a      server*******************************************************

        Properties props = new Properties();
        //System.out.println("File: " + fileName);
        //FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName); // Do this if not on server
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(url.getFile()); // Do this if on Server
        props.load(in);

        String driver = props.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
        urlString = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
        username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
        if (username == null)
            username = "";
        password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
        if (password == null)
            password = "";
        if (driver != null)
            Class.forName(driver);
    }

    /**
     * Gets a connection to the database.
     * 
     * @return the database connection
     */
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(urlString, username, password);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value for the fileName??, please post the string value

Comment: Sorry, the string name is "database.properties"

Comment: The file database.properties is inside a package, or it's in a folder for the web app, can you post the file location.

Comment: Its not in a package.  It is in the top level of my project as follows:  PizzaProjectWeb

Comment: Ignore the previous comment...
Its not in a package.  It is in the top level of my project.  The physical location is C:\Users\Mitch Jordan\workspace2\PizzaProjectWeb\database.properties    where PizzaProjectWeb is my project.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to move the file inside to the src folder, for the next code it must be in the root of the src folder, you can load the file in this way:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();   
properties.load(SimpleDataSource.class.getResourceAsStream("/database.properties"));
```